# Multiple 'Or' conditional evaluator in Python

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I am new to Python and I recently learnt about the 'or' condition evaluator. Could someone explain to the me why the following code gives 'abcd':

```
     'abcd' or 'hijk' or 'lmno'
```

Shouldn't it return True? Also, how does Python evaluate these statements? Does it take 'hijk' or 'lmno' first or does it evaluate 'abcd' or 'hijk'? Basically, is it from right to left or left to right?

Answer (score 5):

This is clearly explained in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

> The expression `x and y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is `false`, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.
>   The expression `x or y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is `true`, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

Answer (score 3):

The way `a or b` works in Python is as follows:

- If `bool(a)` evaluates to `True`, the expression returns `a` (and **not** `True`).
- Otherwise, the expression returns `b`.

Since `bool('abcd')` is `True`, `'abcd' or <anything>` always returns `'abcd'`.

Answer (score 0):

Easy to check:

```
def cond(arg):
  print arg
  return arg

print cond("a") or cond("b") or cond("c")
```

prints "a" twice.
Or evaluation goes from left to right and is lazy, i.e. it stops evaluating subexpressions as soon as the result is known.
A string value which is not None is treated as True when evaluated as a conditional (part of the boolean "or" expression in this case).